# Switching environments within a fabric script

Tags: python, fabric

I want to try to execute this

```
env.host_string = "server1.com"
with cd("/tmp"):
    run("some command)

#switch servers
env.host_string = "server2.com"

with cd("/home"):
    run("some other command")
```

The issue is the commands need to be executed sequentially and not in parrelel. I can't figure out a way to do this in fabric. I've tried `with env("hostname"):` but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [@serial](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/decorators.html?highlight=parallel#fabric.decorators.serial%20@serial) decorator to avoid parallel execution of tasks. You could also try the @hosts decorator (see the same page) to limit each task to a subset of hosts, and argue all hosts when you call Fabric.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using fabric's execute()

```
task_a():
  with cd("/tmp"):
    run("some command")

task_b():
  with cd("/home"):
    run("some other command")

task_c():
  execute(task_a,hosts=["server1.com"])
  execute(task_b,hosts=["server2.com"])
```